# What is this error in apache error.log

Tags: logging, apache-2.4

What is this error in apache error.log and how to fix that problem?:

```
[Sat Jul 25 09:23:11.961977 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4448:tid 140445816444672] [client 127.0.0.1:57067] AH01068: Got bogus version 54, referer: https://domain.tld/board/3-z%C3%BCchten/
[Sat Jul 25 09:23:11.962064 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4448:tid 140445816444672] (22)Invalid argument: [client 127.0.0.1:57067] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (passing brigade to output filters), referer: https://domain.tld/board/3-z%C3%BCchten/
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that when mod_proxy_fcgi tried to check what protocol version was being used, it didn't get any version it accepts. It's explained in the comments around [bug 56110](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56110) - however, that bug pertains to logging the error message, not the actual cause.

There's been another report of this in [bug 57398](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57398). You could add your logs to that one; it might help getting it resolved.